# Python server number calculator

Tags: python

I'm creating a bot for chats it connects through a socket(socket not important) connection but I am trying to figure out how to exactly get the weight so I can connect to the socket to begin with. What I have at the moment works, but I would like to possibly simplify it.

```
    def test(chat):
       local = {'de-livechat': 5,'ver-anime': 8,'watch-dragonball':8,'narutowire': 10,'dbzepisodeorg': 10,'animelinkz':20,'kiiiikiii': 21,'soccerjumbo': 21,'vipstand': 21,'cricket365live': 21,'pokemonepisodeorg': 22, 'watchanimeonn': 22,'leelarp': 27,'animeutamacom': 34,'rgsmotrisport': 41,'cricvid-hitcric-': 51,'tvtvanimefreak': 54,'stream2watch3':56,'mitvcanel':56,'sport24lt':56,'ttvsports':56,'efangames':56,'myfoxdfw':67,'pliculas-flv':69,'narutochatt':70}
       w12,sv2,sv4,sv6,sv8,sv10,sv12=75,95,110,104,101,110,116
       tagservers = [["5", w12], ["6", w12], ["7", w12], ["8", w12], ["16", w12], ["17", w12], ["18", w12], ["9", sv2], ["11", sv2], ["12", sv2], ["13", sv2], ["14", sv2], ["15", sv2], ["19", sv4], ["23", sv4], ["24", sv4], ["25", sv4], ["26", sv4], ["28", sv6], ["29", sv6], ["30", sv6], ["31", sv6], ["32", sv6], ["33", sv6], ["35", sv8], ["36", sv8], ["37", sv8], ["38", sv8], ["39", sv8], ["40", sv8], ["41", sv8], ["42", sv8], ["43", sv8], ["44", sv8], ["45", sv8], ["46", sv8], ["47", sv8], ["48", sv8], ["49", sv8], ["50", sv8], ["52", sv10], ["53", sv10], ["55", sv10], ["57", sv10], ["58", sv10], ["59", sv10], ["60", sv10], ["61", sv10], ["62", sv10], ["63", sv10], ["64", sv10], ["65", sv10], ["66", sv10], ["68", sv2], ["71", sv12], ["72", sv12], ["73", sv12], ["74", sv12], ["75", sv12], ["76", sv12], ["77", sv12], ["78", sv12], ["79", sv12], ["80", sv12], ["81", sv12], ["82", sv12], ["83", sv12], ["84", sv12]]
       try:
           weight = local[chat]
       except:
           chat = chat.replace('-','q').replace('_','q')
           a = int(chat[0:min(5,len(chat))],36)
           b = chat[6:][:min(3,len(chat)-5)]
           b = int(b,36) if len(chat) > 6 else 1000
           total = sum([x[1] for x in tagservers])
           c = a%b/b
           i = 0
           for u in tagservers:
                i+=u[1]/total
                if c <= i:
                     weight = u[0]
                     break
       return 's%s.websitedomainname.com' % weight
```

Doing "test('chatnamehere')" and "test('anotherchatname')" would give 's7.websitedomainname.com' for "chatnamehere" and 's12.websitedomainname.com' for "anotherchatname" if anyone knows a simplified code to do this it would be very much appreciated.